# Python upgrade does not work

Tags: python, python3

I'm trying to update from Python 3.6.8 to Python 3.7.

I followed these steps:

1. ```
   sudo apt-get install python3.7
   ```
2. ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2
   ```
3. ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config python3
   ```

   and choose Python 3.7
4. Check the Python version using `python3 -V`. It shows `Python 3.6.8`.

What can I do?

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: I use the Jetson nano dev kit. It somekind of ubuntu I guess

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate the binary for your python 3.7 installation using either of the following.

```
locate python
```

or

```
sudo find / -type f -name "python3.7*" 2>/dev/null
```

If you are able to find the right executable, you might need to add it to your PATH environment variable. Otherwise, there might have been some other sort of issue with the installation.